# Hibernate Validator not always validating constraints of ElementType.TYPE_USE

Tags: bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I have defined a constraint with target `TYPE_USE`. When I use this annotation on a field its validator is not running. If I change the the target to `FIELD` then it is. Why doesn't the validator run for this specific example?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

        Set<ConstraintViolation<Test>> violations = validator.validate(new Test("ams"));
        System.out.println(violations); // was expecting a violation but got none
    }

    public static class Test {
        @AirportId
        private final String airport;

        public Test(String airport) {
            this.airport = airport;
        }
    }

    @Documented
    @Target(TYPE_USE)
    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    @Constraint(validatedBy = AirportIdValidator.class)
    public @interface AirportId {
        public String message() default "";
        public Class<?>[] groups() default {};
        public Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
    }

    public static class AirportIdValidator implements ConstraintValidator<AirportId, String> {
        @Override
        public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```